# Dispatching mouse event to iframe window?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have two sibling divs (absolute positioned).

```
    ________________
    |              |
    |  BACK DIV    |
    |     _________|_____
    |     |             |
    |     |  FRONT DIV  |
    |_____|             |
          |             |
          |_____________|
```

After some efforts I managed to dispatch event from one div to other div.

```
var backDiv = document.getElementById('back');
var frontDiv = document.getElementById('front');
var logger = document.getElementById('logger');

backDiv.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    logger.innerHTML += 'back<br />';
});

frontDiv.addEventListener('mousedown',function(e) {
    logger.innerHTML += 'front<br />';

    var e1 = document.createEvent('MouseEvent');
    e1.initMouseEvent(e.type, e.bubbles, e.cancelable, e.view, e.detail, e.screenX, e.screenY, e.clientX, e.clientY, e.ctrlKey, e.altKey, e.shiftKey, e.metaKey, e.button, null);

    console.log(backDiv.contentWindow)
    backDiv.contentWindow.document.body.dispatchEvent(e1);
}, true);
```

Here's the [code](http://jsfiddle.net/aneelkkhatri/9S55Y/1/).
After I place an iframe at the back and div at front,

```
    ________________
    |              |
    | BACK IFRAME  |
    |     _________|_____
    |     |             |
    |     |  FRONT DIV  |
    |_____|             |
          |             |
          |_____________|
```

I want to dispatch mouse event from front div into iframe.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a parent element (say #container) to iframe, then:

```
var event = document.createEvent('Event');
event.initEvent('CustomEvent', true, true);
event.targetFrame = "myTargetFrame";
element = parent.document.getElementById('container');
element.dispatchEvent(event);
```

and remember to listen to events fired in parent document

```
parent.document.addEventListener('CustomEvent', function(e) {
    if(e.targetFrame == "myTargetFrame") {
        // codes here
    }
});
```

and because you checked the target frame, there won't be any conflicts in events triggered for multiple frames